# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values' using reshape

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression

I'm trying to reshape data into two-dimensional data structure so I can use it in Sklear, I keep getting an error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values' 
and when I tried removing values from-- Xtrain.values.reshape(-1, 1) I get another error saying : Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

```
import pandas as pd 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np 
    data = pd.read_csv('loan_defaults.csv')
    data = pd.get_dummies(data, drop_first=True)

    data.groupby('default').mean()
    data.corr()

    defaultN = data.query('default == 0')
    defaultY= data.query('default == 1')


    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(data.balance, data.default, random_state = 0)

    Xtrain = Xtrain.values.reshape(-1, 1)
    Xtest  = Xtest.values.reshape(-1, 1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
log_reg = LogisticRegression(class_weight="balanced")

log_reg.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)

log_reg.intercept_
log_reg.coef_

log_reg.predict_proba(100)
log_reg.predict(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

No real need to add values after performing `train_test_split` as the output is an array itself. Simply try with:

```
Xtrain = Xtrain.reshape(-1,1)
Xtest = Xtest.reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: That is not part of the question, please open another question to address a different issue, of edit your question if the issue relates to the original question.

Comment: Thanks 
just uploaded the whole thing